# How to use webpack build with ionic capacitor?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a project on Ionic , there was a need to use alias in TypeScript , put together an assembly in webpack everything works fine .

But when trying to build a project with a team ( ionic capacitor copy android ) for android , difficulties appeared .  Since by default, the capacitor uses react-scripts to build.

[image]

Consequently, react-scripts is not aware of my alias paths, and throws an error.

[image]

Is there a solution to this problem ? I want to use my webpack configuration instead of react-scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the help of [capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs)  by creating a simple project on it,
since in the capacitor.config we specify the directory of the finished build to the project, the capacitor itself just takes these files and works with them already, in this case the project assembly remains for webpack where I specified my alias paths.